# Error starting Web sphere 8.5 application server

Tags: windows, eclipse, websphere-8, ibm-rad

Recently, Websphere 8.5 application server has been corrupted. 

I receive the below error while starting the server.

Have uninstalled the server completely and reinstalled again.
Tried to start the server from startServer.bat in IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\bin folder.

I don't see any errors in the server logs

---

`[4/25/19 15:01:42:789 CDT] 00000001 ManagerAdmin  I   TRAS0017I: The startup trace state is =info:com.ibm.=all.
[4/25/19 15:01:42:804 CDT] 00000001 WsServerContr 1   Executing executeUtilityOnWindows with args: C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\config L00W10P0014960Node01Cell L00W10P0014960Node01 server1 -script C:\D\My_Ws.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\quickServerStart.bat 
[4/25/19 15:01:42:805 CDT] 00000001 ManagerAdmin  I   TRAS0018I: The trace state has changed. The new trace state is *=info.
[4/25/19 15:01:42:885 CDT] 00000001 AdminTool     A   ADMU0128I: Starting tool with the AppSrv01 profile
[4/25/19 15:01:42:889 CDT] 00000001 AdminTool     A   ADMU3100I: Reading configuration for server: server1
[4/25/19 15:01:43:166 CDT] 00000001 ModelMgr      I   WSVR0801I: Initializing all server configuration models
[4/25/19 15:01:48:026 CDT] 00000001 WorkSpaceMana A   WKSP0500I: Workspace configuration consistency check is disabled.
[4/25/19 15:01:48:203 CDT] 00000001 AdminTool     A   ADMU3300I: Launch script for server created: C:\D\My_Ws.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\quickServerStart.bat`

Thanks for the help in advance

ClassNotFoundException: Files/microsoft

---

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something in your launch command needs quotation marks around it - something is pointing at a path within "Program Files\Microsoft " but does not have it within quotes, so Java sees the spaces and thinks "Files\Microsoft" is its own argument to Java. Presumably, this is before the actual Java class that launches the server, so Java reads it as the main class it should launch, and it fails because you obviously don't have a class called "Files\Microsoft".

Creating a launch script was an excellent move. Open quickServerStart.bat and search for "Program Files\Microsoft", determine where the quotation marks need to be in order to keep that whole argument together, add them, and see if that gets your server up and running. If you're able to do that, at least you're functional while you fix your configuration.

Given what you've shared of the failure, my guess is that the issue is a JVM argument added to the server process. Ideally, if you can get the server to start using the generated launch script, you can fix it through the admin console (it'd be in the Server -> Process Definition -> Java Virtual Machine page). If you can't get the server to launch, then you'll want to go to the config/cells/(cellname)/nodes/(nodename)/servers/(servername) directory and hand-edit server.xml (back up the file first!). Again, search for "Program Files\Microsoft" and determine whether it actually belongs there, and if so, where you can add surrounding quotation marks to make it into a contained argument.

Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. Now I remember, after installing the visual studio code, env variable has been updated with reference to Program File/Microsoft which has been referred in quickServerStart.bat Launch Command. Will try uninstalling the VSC and see

Comment: Figured the issue was the system variable had an entry with ;\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft. Able to start the server once its been cleared out and restarted the system